# Return tabledata as file with jquery and c# mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I would like to use jquery to send Table-data to the server and then get a data.csv file to download

if i navigate to the url in my browser like this:
http://localhost:49400/File/Csv/?Text=qweerty&Filename=asdf
i get promted with a file to download.

This is the action im calling:

```
    public FileResult Csv(FileModel fileModel)
    {
        return File(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileModel.Text), "text/plain", string.Concat(fileModel.Filename, ".csv"));
    }
```

and my javascript looks like this:

```
    $("table").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:49400/File/Csv/",
            data: {"Text": "qwerty", "Filename": "asdf"}
        })
    });
```

The response in firebug is containing the data, but i would like it to ask the user if it wants to download it, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use AJAX to download a file.

Instead, you can just set `location` to a URL pointing to the file.
As long as the server returns a downloadable file (with a `Content-Disposition` header), the browser will show a Save dialog and will not replace the page.

If you want to download the file from a POST, you could make a hidden `<form>` that sends the POST, then `submit()` the form using Javascript.

Comment: created a form with javascript and submitted it with the data and got a file back, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can't deliver file content through ajax call, perhaps find a way to construct URL with your table data as query string and stream the file that way or post-back the whole page and response as a stream